# jQuery: Event sequence with dynamically bound, arbitrarily created events & listeners not completing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Need to be able to arbitrarily create events (even those created during runtime) and then arbitrarily bind event listeners for such events to elements.

In the code below, *everything* works exactly as planned except that `XBS.pullCurtain()` is never called (but the event fires!). I've checked and rechecked the arguments, the sequence, etc.—no errors are thrown, everything appears to be what I'm expecting. But no sauce from the event listener. :S

```
 // this func is used in the larger object below
function eCustom(eName, eProperties) {
            var defaultProps = {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false, "eventPhase":0, "type":eName};
            if (typeof(eProperties) == "object") {
                for (var prop in eProperties) {
                    if (eProperties.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
                        defaultProps[prop] = eProperties[prop];
                    }
                }
            }
            return jQuery.Event(eName, defaultProps);
}

window.XBS = {
        cfg: {
            minLoadTime: 1000
        },
        evnt: {
            wakeFromSleep: eCustom("wakeFromSleep"),
            assetsLoaded: eCustom("assetsLoaded")
        },
        init: {
            // obviously will be expanded haha
            XBS.initImages();
        },
        stopwatch: {
            __sw: new Date(),
            reset:function() { XBS.stopwatch.startTime = -1},
            start: function() {
                var now = XBS.stopwatch.__sw.getTime();
                XBS.stopwatch.startTime = now;
                return now;
            },
            read: function() { return XBS.stopwatch.__sw.getTime() - XBS.stopwatch.start;},
            now: function() { return XBS.stopwatch.__sw.getTime();},
            elapsed: function(period) {
                var diff = XBS.stopwatch.now() - XBS.stopwatch.startTime;
                return (period !== undefined) ? diff > period : diff;
            },
            startTime:-1
        },
        sleep: function(period, wakeEvent, onWake, target) {
            if (wakeEvent == undefined) wakeEvent = XBS.evnt.wakeFromSleep;
            if (isFunction(onWake) ) {
                // confirmed code reaches these lines and all vars are as expected
                if (target == undefined) target = window;
                $(target).on(wakeEvent, onWake);
            }
            setTimeout(function() {$(target).trigger(wakeEvent) }, period);
        },
        initImages: function() {
            XBS.stopwatch.start();
            // loadImages is a jQuery extension (link at bottom), but it works like a charm—
            // problem isn't there, I'm 99% sure
            $("#image-loading-queue").loadImages({
                allLoadedClb:function() {
                    var success = null;
                //minLoadTime because there will be presentational animations
                    if (XBS.stopwatch.elapsed(XBS.cfg.minLoadTime)) {
                        success = true;
                    } else {
                        var elapsed = XBS.cfg.minLoadTime - XBS.stopwatch.elapsed();
                        XBS.sleep(elapsed, XBS.evnt.wakeFromSleep, XBS.pullCurtain, "#curtain");
                    }
                }
            });
            // this return is a placeholder for pending functionality, which is why it's not used
            return success;
        },
        pullCurtain: function() {
            // this will get more elaborate, but for now, I just want to call the darn thing!
            $("#curtain").fadeToggle();
        }
    }
```

Borrowed Library:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Asynchronous-Image-Loading-with-jQuery-Image-Loader-Plugin.html

Comment: Can you try and reduce your sample code to the smallest fragment necessary to run and reproduce the problem? If possible, create an example case on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which reproduces the issue. Most of the rest of the code is likely irrelevant to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***jsFiddle demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/j4LxLyg0/)

You have an error in your jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method call (which your JavaScript console is probably complaining about). The first parameter to `on` should only be the name of the event to handle (a string), not a jQuery Event object. Take a look at the documentation. It has two signatures: one which takes the method name (e.g. `'click'`) and one which takes a map of multiple method names to functions (e.g. `{'click': fn1, 'mouseover': fn2}`). It doesn't have a method signature for jQuery Event objects.

When you bind the handler, change the line to pass the event name only:

```
$(target).on(wakeEvent.type, onWake);
```

Comment: Nice catch, would never have flund that, tyvm.